# How can I create queue in Julia with different elements

Tags: julia

I want to make a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) with different elements like below. Would you please help me?

```
pq=[[-4;5,5;9,rectangle,horizontal],[-6;8,4;7,z2,Triangle,vertical]];
```

Comment: Code format fixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a `Queue` data type in [DataStructures.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl) (install and load via `Pkg.add("DataStructures"); using DataStructures;`). In particular have a look at the [documentation](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/latest/queue/). Taken from a previous version of that page:

```
q = Queue{Int}()
enqueue!(q, x)
x = front(q)
x = back(q)
x = dequeue!(q)
```

To put elements of different type into the queue you could use a `Queue{Any}()` or replace `Any` by the appropriate `Union` type.

Example:

```
julia> using DataStructures

julia> q = Queue{Any}();

julia> enqueue!(q, "This is a string.");

julia> enqueue!(q, 3.141);

julia> enqueue!(q, 123);

julia> enqueue!(q, Queue{Int}());

julia> for x in q
           println(x)
       end
This is a string.
3.141
123
Queue{Int64}(Deque [Int64[]])
```